# How to set different font color in combobox items in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a `ComboBox` in Flex which is listing like this:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F

A-B-C-D-E-F-*

A-B-C-D-E-F-G-*

A-B-C-D-E-F-*
```

I want to make the `*` appear red. Could anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: The items are in String format

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully self-explaining:

```
<s:ComboBox itemRendererFunction="getItemRenderer" 
    dataProvider="{new ArrayList(['A-B-C-D-E-F', 'A-B-C-D-E-F-', 'A-B-C-D-E-F-G-', 'A-B-C-D-E-F-'])}"/>

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component className="RedItemRenderer">
        <s:ItemRenderer>
            <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle">
                <s:Label text="{data}" color="red" paddingLeft="3" paddingRight="3" paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="5"/>
                <s:Image source="@Embed(source='warning.png')"/>
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:ItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script><![CDATA[

    import mx.collections.ArrayList;        
    import spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer;

    private function getItemRenderer(item:Object):IFactory
    {
        var s:String = item as String;
        if (s.charAt(s.length-1) == '-')
            return new ClassFactory(RedItemRenderer);
        else
            return new ClassFactory(DefaultItemRenderer);
    }

]]></fx:Script>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I want to append an "warning image icon" to the text instead of " * ". Could you please help me to do this

Comment: @BiswajitDas You should better describe your question - that's why you are downvoted - because it was not exactly clear before your comment what the problem is.

Comment: @BiswajitDas If this answers your question then you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark. Also it is advisable to improve your question, so other visitors can better understand it. Maybe the downvotes are rectracted.